# Definition of derivative for $n$D functions

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

[image]

After reading this text from PMA Rudin I have couple questions.

1) My first question about existence of 1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $L(\mathbb{R}^1)$.

Let's $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^1$ then we can associate with this $\lambda$ real function, namely $f(x)=\lambda x\in L(\mathbb{R}^1)$. We prove that this correspondence is injective. Let's $\lambda_1 x=\lambda_2x$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^1$. Then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^1\setminus\{0\}$. But for $x=0$ we could have that $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ and this little bit confuses me.
How to prove surjective? That for any $f\in L(\mathbb{R}^1)$ we have that $f(x)=\lambda x$ for some real $\lambda$.

Comment: What does it mean for two functions to be equal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, that $f(x)=g(x)$ for any $x$ where $f,g$ are defined.

Comment: For **all**, not for **any**. I guess that's his point.

Comment: So if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two real numbers, and $f(x)=\lambda x$ and $g(x)=\mu x$ are the corresponding linear functions, what does it mean for $f$ and $g$ to be equal?

Comment: @pre-kidney, using *any* for *all* is normal — the problem would be *some*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, $\lambda x=\mu x$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^1$. Right?

Comment: Can you think of a useful value of $x$ that you can use that equality with?

Comment: We can conclude that for $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ we have $\lambda=\mu$. Right?

Comment: How did you conclude that? (I cannot tell if «we can conclude» if you do not tell me *how* you conclude...)

Comment: Though for $x=1$ we have $\mu=\lambda$. So what?

Comment: Yes, that $f=g$ means that $\lambda x=\mu x$ for all $x$ and, in particular, taking $x=1$, that $\lambda=\mu$. («So what»?...)

Comment: (I suggest —if you are not aware of this— that you do not use the «so what?», as it can easiy be interpreted as rude,  or, if you are, that you do not be rude)

Answer (score 1):

The injectivity statement is that if the functions $\lambda_1 x$ and $\lambda_2 x$ are the same, then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$. If two functions are the same, then they evaluate to the same number at $x=1$, so in particular this implies $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$. We never need to say anything about $x=0$!

For surjectivity, let $f\colon \mathbb R^1\to\mathbb R^1$ be an arbitrary linear function and let $\lambda=f(1)$. By linearity, it follows that $f(x)=\lambda x$ and hence $f(x)$ has the desired form.

Comment: About surjectivity. You wrote that "By linearity.." how you used linearity?

Comment: A linear function has the property $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$ for any real numbers $a$ and $b$, by definition. In particular, $f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=xf(1)$.

Comment: Ohh right! May I ask you another question? Why we can regard derivative as linear operator? I can't understand it from Rudin's book.

Comment: Because "slopes add": if $f$ and $g$ are functions, then the derivative of $f+g$ is the sum of the derivative of $f$ and the derivative of $g$.

Comment: So what? I think that above does not matter. It's little bit meaningless

Comment: If you find the last statement meaningless, then perhaps you should review the concept of a linear operator. You'll find (after you have gained some intuition) that it boils down to what I have said. But I appreciate that it might appear meaningless to you right now.